# Is there a Google Apps Script for Fuzzy Lookups?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fuzzy-logic

I have a list of companies on a spreadsheet that is rarely updated. I'll call it List A.

I also have a constantly updating weekly list of companies (List B) that should have entries that match some entries on List A.

The reality is that the data extracted from List B's company names are often inconsistent due to various business abbreviations (e.g. The Company, Company Ltd., Company Accountants Limited). Sometimes, these companies are under different trading names or have various mispellings.

My initial very not intelligent reaction was to construct a table of employer alias names, with the first column being the true employer name and the following columns holding alises, something like this: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cmYv.png]

On the left is a sample table, and the far right is a column where I am using the following array formula template:

`=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A30:A33,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(B30:E33=H30),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B30:E33)^0)),0)))`

I realized soon after that I needed to create a new entry for every single exact match variation (Ltd., Ltd, and Limited), so I looked into fuzzy lookups. I was really impressed by [Alan's Fuzzy Matching UDFs](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.195635/), but my needs heavily lean towards using Google Spreadsheets rather than VBA.

Sorry for the long post, but I would be grateful if anyone has any good suggestions for fuzzy lookups or can suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: Why tag excel? You ask about google...

Comment: May be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486078

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468119/fuzzy-match-on-google-sheets

Comment: Did the previous comments help you find a solution? Could you maybe share a sample sheet to try to replicate your problem? You could try to replicate *Alan's Fuzzy Matching* in 'Apps Script'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments weren't exactly what I was looking for, but they did provide some inspiration for me to come up with a bandaid solution.

My original array formula needed exact matches, but the problem was that there were simply too many company suffixes and alternate names, so I looked into fuzzy lookups.

My current answer is to abandon the fuzzy lookup proposal and instead focus on editing the original data string (i.e. company names) into more simplified substring. Grabbing with a few codes floating around, I came up with a combined custom formula that implements two lines for GApps Script:

```
 var companysuffixremoval = str.toString().replace(/limited|ltd|group|holdings|plc|llp|sons|the/ig, "");

 var alphanumericalmin = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g,"")
```

The first line is simply my idea of removing popular company suffixes and the "the" from the string.

The second line is removing all non-alphanumerical characters, as well as any spaces and periods.

This ensure "The First Company Limited." and "First Company Ltd" become "FirstCompany", which should work with returning the same values from the original array formula in the OP. Of course, I also implemented a trimming and cleaning line for any trailing/leading/extra spaces for the initial string, but that's probably unncessary with the second line.

If someone can come up with a better idea, please do tell. As it stands, I'm just tinkering with a script with minimal experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to modify your strings by removing certain portions, then I suggest that you use the [NORMALIZE](https://www.getflookup.com/documentation/spreadsheet-functions#h.6m0evbs0c19y) function from a Google Sheets add-ons I created called [Flookup](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/flookup/593806014962). It is completely free to use, even without any registration.
Here is how to use it:

1. In a cell of your choice, like cell C2, enter a comma separated array of the strings you would like to remove i.e. `limited, ltd, group, holdings, plc, llp, sons, the`
2. In cell B2, type the following formula: `=NORMALIZE("text",$A$2:$A$4,$C$2)`

This formula will work through every item in range A2:A4 and strip any string found in cell C2.

---

If you would like to try fuzzy lookups, you can use a function called [FLOOKUP](https://www.getflookup.com/documentation/spreadsheet-functions#h.dho9lnim1i2l). This is its syntax and what each parameter represents:

```
FLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, lookup_col, index_num, threshold, [rank])
```

- **lookup_value:** the value you're looking up
- **table_array:** the table you want to search lookup_col: the column you
  want to search
- **index_num:** the column you want data to be returned from
- **threshold:** the percentage similarity below which data shouldn't be returned
- **rank:** the nth best match (i.e. if the first one is not to your liking)